# ndk-gdb with Android Studio

Tags: c++, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-gdb

I was previously able to use eclipse to build an android app with ndk-build and I was able to debug using the ndk-gdb. When I do the same on the app built using Android Studio, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Non-debuggable application installed on the target device.
       Please re-install the debuggable version!
```

I have set jniDebuggable=true in build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable true
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

**Note:** I have tested on Samsung S3, Moto-g Second Generation. I tried with r9d, 10c and 10d.